# Does turning off blood affect gameplay?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag, does turning off blood disable any moves or any finishers?

Or is it strictly the blood effect and you can still perform every move?

Comment: I wouldn't say so... The blood is just there for show. Unless he does something weird like catch some blood in a glass and drink it or something... Which I highly doubt they would have added since AC3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straight answer is: **NO** and **You will have all the finishers and moves**

As you said in the title of your question : **blood effect**

> It's a visual effect only. When you swing your sword at enemies and
>   hit them it triggers the effect.
>
> So, if you turn it off it just doesn't trigger that effect anymore and
>   the blood won't appear and **you will continue to be able to perform
>   all the moves and finishers in the game.**

Answer (score -1):

Not at all. I personally prefer it on, but that's just because I've not got any squeamishness towards blood, and no children in the house.